# How to serve a pdf file from ember

Tags: pdf, ember.js

I want to make a pdf document available via a link from my ember app, so I figured I would put the file in `/public/assets/pdf/` and link to it as
`<a href='/assets/pdf/myfile.pdf'>` just as I would for an image in `public/assets/images`. However the link isn't sending the file to the browser. I get a 200 response with a `Content-Type: application/pdf` header, but no file.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described should work as there's nothing special about the way Ember handles static asset downloads. To verify, I just initialized a new project using Ember 2.3 and placed a pdf in /assets/test.pdf. I then placed the following into my application.hbs file.

```
<a href='/assets/test.pdf' download>Test</a>
```

Without the download attribute it opened as a new tab. With the download attribute the file was downloaded like normal.